# Replace dim3 in matlab array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

If assumed a 3x3x3 array, how does one replace the entire dim3 if a condition is met? Whith given array

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 1 6; 7 8 1];
A(:, :, 2) = [1 2 3; 4 2 6; 7 8 2]
A(:, :, 3) = [1 2 3; 4 3 6; 7 8 3]
```

In this simple case there is two dim3s containing `[1 2 3]`, on `A(2,2,:)` and `A(3,3,:)`. How could I replace them with `[10 10 10]` for example. This seems very simple but I just can't get my head around it...

Edit: I acidentaly oversimplifiyed the probelem, the replacemnt Vector should  be more something like `[11 12 13]` finding the (X,Y)-index is not the actual problem.

I am looking for a clean and memory efficient way to replace `A(2,2,:)` and `A(3,3,:)` with [11 12 13] obtaining the output:
    A(:,:,1) =

```
     1     2     3
     4    11     6
     7     8    11


A(:,:,2) =

     1     2     3
     4    12     6
     7     8    12


A(:,:,3) =

     1     2     3
     4    13     6
     7     8    13
```

Curcial in this case, is that I don't know how many emements are to be replaced in the real world problem...

Comment: The replacement is just `A(2,2,:) = 10;`  or `A(3,3,:) = 10;` Are you also asking how to find if that condition exists?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What are the inputs and desired output (in your example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some logical indexing (Matlab 2016b and later):

```
target = [1 2 3]; % the vector you want to find
replacement = [11 12 13]; % the vector you want to replace it with

% find the 2d indexes where the target is found
idx = all(A == permute(target,[1 3 2]),3); 
% replace found indexes with replacement vector
A(logical(idx.*ones(1,1,size(A,3)))) = repelem(replacement,1,nnz(idx));
```

Same thing for Matlab pre 2016b:

```
idx = all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(target,[1 3 2])),3);
A(logical(bsxfun(@times,idx,ones(1,1,size(A,3))))) = repelem(replacement,1,nnz(idx));
```

Comment: Thank your very much! Interestingly it is not faster than the verison with the loop. At least for a `2769x2694x3 uint8`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the elements along the third dimension is just an assignment.

```
A(2,2,:) = 10;
A(:,:,1) =
     1     2     3
     4    10     6
     7     8     1    
A(:,:,2) =
     1     2     3
     4    10     6
     7     8     2 
A(:,:,3) =
     1     2     3
     4    10     6
     7     8     3
```

If you are trying to identify where you have the 1,2,3 pattern along the third dimension you could do something like this:

```
idx= A(:,:,1) == 1 & A(:,:,2) ==2 & A(:,:,3) == 3;
idx= repmat(idx,1,1,3);
A(idx) = 10;
```

Which results in:

```
A(:,:,1) =
     1     2     3
     4    10     6
     7     8    10
A(:,:,2) =
     1     2     3
     4    10     6
     7     8    10
A(:,:,3) =
     1     2     3
     4    10     6
     7     8    10
```

Comment: Cheers That certainly helps - I think I mad a mistake with my question by giving `[10 10 10]` as replacement - I acutually want to put a vector like `[10 11 12]` so the simple index does not work for this case...

Answer (score 0):

I somehow worked out a solution based on 'Aero Engy's previous post It's however very ugly as it requires asignments in a loop - does someone have an idea for a vectorized version?

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 1 6; 7 8 1];
A(:, :, 2) = [1 2 3; 4 2 6; 7 8 2];
A(:, :, 3) = [1 2 3; 4 3 6; 7 8 3];

Target = [1 2 3];
Replacement = [11 12 13];

idx = find(A(:,:,1) == Target(1) & A(:,:,2) == Target(2) & A(:,:,3) == Target(3));
[x, y, ~] = ind2sub(size(A), idx);

for i = 1:length(x) 
A(x(i), y(i), 1) = Replacement(1);
A(x(i), y(i), 2) = Replacement(2);
A(x(i), y(i), 3) = Replacement(3);
end
```